# eclipseとpostgresの接続

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipse, spring-boot

spring-bootの参考書に沿って勉強をしていたのですが、データベースに登録が出来ず、
インストールしたpgAdminとEclipseを接続しなければならないのかと思い、検索してみたのですが、
下記のサイト通りのディレクトリにpostgresのファイルが存在しません。
恐らく私がインストールしているeclipseが2022年の日本語版のeclipseをインストールしているのが原因とも感じるのですが、これが原因かははっきりしていません。
https://workteria.forward-soft.co.jp/blog/detail/10312

インストールしたpostgresファイルにも登録できるようなファイルがありませんでした。

Comment: どういうコードを書きどんな操作を行った結果、どういうエラーが発生したのかといった事実を具体的に記述する必要があるように思われます。現状の質問文は質問者の想像ベースで記載されているので、他者が見たとき実際に何が起こっているのかが把握できないと考えます。ちなみに「pgAdminとEclipseを接続する」(というのが実際には何をしたいのか意図を掴みかねますが、言葉通り受け取るなら)必要はありません。